# Trouble with opening docx file, seems to be Unicode issue

Tags: python, python-docx

I am a novice to python & this is my first small project

I am having trouble inputting a file directory to open a Word document. I tried this by copying & pasting the directory from my command prompt, but this Error appears after plugging it in. How do I convert the command prompt to UTF-8 or find the directory in Unicode?

#After importing necessary modules for the project, I access the file

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd

import docx


doc = Document('C:\Users\trisy\OneDrive\Desktop\classes\SP_22_courses\CS1110\pye_files\kw_txt.docx')
```

#Error message

```
doc = Document('C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\Desktop\classes\SP_22_courses\xxx\pye_files\kw_txt.docx')
                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the backslashes in that pathname, combined with certain other characters.

In Python, putting `\x` in a string can have special behavior depending on what `x` is.

For example, `\n` does not mean "backslash n"; it means a newline character.

`\U` is one of these special cases.

To get around this, you have two options:

1. Use "raw strings".  Put an `r` before the string.  `r'C:\Users\...'` The `r` tells Python that backslashes should have no special meaning.
2. Use forward slashes in the file path.  `'C:/Users/...'` These will work even on Windows.